# Why do I need to backup iTunes?

Tags: windows-7, backup, itunes

I got a message in iTunes saying:

> "Thank you for purchasing from the iTunes Store. 
>   Protect your purchases by backing them up"

erm. Isn't that what my Apple id is for?

I thought the whole point of iTunes is that I can re-download my iTunes library if my PC ever crashes because apple knows what all my purchases are.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While Apps from App store maybe downloaded without a limit, content such as media, music, Videos are often exempt from the unlimited-download-clause. iTunes Store's [conditions mentions](http://www.apple.com/legal/itunes/us/terms.html#SERVICE):

> **Some iTunes Products**, including but not limited to Content rentals, **may be downloaded only once and cannot be replaced** if lost for any reason. It is your responsibility not to lose, destroy, or damage iTunes Products once downloaded, and you may wish to back them up.

It's for this reason Apple asks you to back up your data

Comment: not satisfied by the vagueness in the terms & conditions, i.e. the difference between 'Eligible Content' which you can re-download and 'some iTunes Products' but that's not your fault. I blame the legal profession.

Comment: You should be blaming the content 'creators.'  They are the ones that have a monopoly on the content and force Apple to only allow downloads once.  Then blame Apple itself for the vagueness of the Terms & Conditions as the decision to use such vague language is a business decision made from the top, in order to allow them to later choose other products that they no longer want to host on their servers.  The legal profession would make it as specific as possible, it's the business people that increase the ambiguity so they don't have to provide extra hosting.

Comment: I am shocked the terms still mention limited downloads because movies and tv show purchases no longer have a single download limit.  TV show rentals and movie rentals are an entirely different question.  **Its best to stream those anyways since you have to have internet connection to start playing them evne if you download them in full.**

Comment: @NickKavadias which part?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can re-download your purchases but your playlists, ratings, and other personalizations are not retained in iCloud.

If your HD crashes not only would you have to go back and re-download everything (which is I believe to be manual still), you would have to create all your playlists, ratings, and such that you have made within iTunes itself all over again.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is simply a remnant of history. Until fairly recently, it was not possible to re-download any content. I had a number of songs that were on a drive that died, and I couldn't get at them until Apple implemented iCloud. It would seem that Apple kept the message because, after all, it's not bad advice!